# Как короче сверстать данный блок?

Tags: css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.logo {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex; }

.span-logo1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px; }

.span-logo2 {
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px; }

.tel {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center; }

.tel__span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold; }

.menu__poloska {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px; }
  .menu__poloska:nth-child(1) {
    margin-top: 3px;
    height: 3px; }
  .menu__poloska:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 40px; }
  .menu__poloska:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 9px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: grey; }

.tel__button {
  background-color: #FFB130;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px; }

.xar {
  margin-top: 40px; }

.xar__text {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px; }
  .xar__text:before {
    content: '';
    border-left: 5px solid  #FFB130;
    padding-left: 30px; }

.xar__text1 {
  margin-left: 32%; }

.xar__text2 {
  margin: 0; }

.xar__text3 {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-right: 5px solid #FFB130;
  margin-right: 31%;
  padding-right: 30px; }
  .xar__text3:before {
    content: ''; }

.xar__text4 {
  border-right: 5px solid #FFB130;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="logo">
    <span class='span-logo1'>мебельная эволюция</span>
    <span class='span-logo2'>Производство и продажа трансформируемой  мебели по Москве и МО</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="tel">
    <span class='tel__span'>8 (499) 647 55 57</span>
    <button class='tel__button'>Заказать звонок</button>
    <div class="menu">
     <span class=" menu__poloska menu__poloska1"></span>
     <span class=" menu__poloska menu__poloska2"></span>
     <span class=" menu__poloska menu__poloska3"></span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <h1 class='header_h1'>
    Кровать - трансформер <br>
    сделает ваш дом просторным, <br>
    а сон - здоровым
   </h1>
   <div class="xar">
    <div class="xar1">
     <p class="xar__text xar__text1">
      установим <br> через 3 недели
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="xar1">
     <p class="xar__text xar__text2">
      гарантия <br> 2 года
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="xar1">
     <p class="xar__text3">
      собственное  <br> производство 
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="xar1">
     <p class="xar__text4">
      экономит 8 м <sup>2</sup><br>пространства
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: я так понимаю это фрагмент слайдера ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/MWwOqEb

Comment: MaximLensky да, Вы правы

Comment: тут придётся здорово пои..ся что бы адаптировать это ..слайдер не проблема - проблема адаптировать это

Comment: MaximLensky понятно спасибо